# How to Make a Constructor Private in a Module but Still Allow for External Construction

Tags: typescript

I want to make a class within a module constructable only via a helper function from that given module so that no (module external) user of that class can construct it without the helper function.

Short usage example:

```
//module: email.ts

export class Email {
    //implementation details
}

export function tryParse(x: string): Email | null {
    //implementation details
}
```

and then later I'd like to use it like this:

```
//module: email_usage.ts
import {Email, tryParse} from "./email.ts"

//works
let x?: Email = tryParse("juhu@yahoo.com")

//but this should fail with an compiler error
let y: Email = new Email("foo")
```

I have a solution for the above ... but it feels quite strange thou

```
export class Email {
    //I need to make the constructor protected here so it cant be accessed outside
    protected constructor(x: string) {
        this._value = x
    }
    private _value: string
    get Value () {
        return this._value
    }
}

//then I create a "Factory" class that extends from Mail so I have access to the protected constructor
class EmailFactory extends Email {
    // and then I create a "public" static method to finally create an Email instance
    static create(x: string): Email {
        return new Email(x)
    }
}

export function tryParse(x: string): Email | null {
    return EmailFactory.create(x)
}
```

I am bit stomped that there is no such access modifier for module internal access (or I havent found it). Any other suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: May be tryParse should be inside Email class and be protected, and you can have paramerless constructor which usually public. Inside factory you pass in new Email object to call tryParse, no need for inheritance. I think it’s “momento” design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I have used before would be to move your `tryParse` helper into the `Email` class itself as a static method, and since it's inside the class, it can access the private contstructor:

```js
export class Email {
    static tryParse(x: string): Email | null {
        return new Email(x)
    }

    private constructor(x: string) {
        this._value = x
    }

    private _value: string

    get Value () {
        return this._value
    }
}

// Then you can construct the email like so:

let x = Email.tryParse("juhu@yahoo.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is just avoid exporting the Email class and only export the tryParse function from your module. You could include it in a factory class similar to what your doing like so:

```
// module A
class Email {
    private _value: string;

    constructor(x: string) {
        this._value = x;
    }
   
    get Value() {
        return this._value;
    }
}

export class EmailFactory extends Email {
    public static parse(x: string): Email {
        return isValidEmail(x) ? new Email(x) : null;
    }
}

// module B
import {EmailFactory} from "ModuleA";

EmailFactory.parse("foo");
// => null
EmailFactory.parse("juhu@yahoo.com");
// => Email
new Email("juhu@yahoo.com");
// error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Email'.
```